# how do you split an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, return-value

Im trying to do a simple string splitting function, but im having a problem returning the split string.

i got the string into strings s1, s2, s3. how do i return `{s1,s2,s3}`? im using brackets but the compiler is telling me

```
expected primary-expression before '{' token 
expected `;' before '{' token 
expected `;' before '}' token
```

even though there doesnt seem to be any problem. is doing `{s1,s2,s3}` even allowed?

Comment: Please include a code snippet in your post. How are you trying to split the string? There may be a function in the standard library that already does what you need (hint: `strtok`).

Comment: No, `retun {s1,s2,s3};` is not valid C++.

Comment: ok. thanks. i must say, c++ is a bit annoying

Comment: That which doesn't kill you makes you a better programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to return type `vector<string>`. Then in your function create a vector and return it as a value.

Comment: Just "accept" whichever answer you found clearest and we'll all be happy :)

Answer (score 3):

You should populate a `std::vector` and return that.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(/*...*/)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // ...
    result.push_back(s); // s: s1 - s3
    // ...

    return result;
}
```

Note you shouldn't actually have the variables `s1`, `s2`, or `s3`, or you're just limiting the process to three outputs. You should have a loop through the string, pushing results into the vector.

Comment: Woa, our answers are almost identical... :S

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You have to put your strings in an appropriate container that will be returned by your function; you could use, for example, `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> YourFunction(/* ... */)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    // ...
    ret.push_back(s); // you should call this for each string
    // ...
    return ret;
}
```

Thanks to [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) this shouldn't be as heavyweight as it may seem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid syntax at all. If you have C++0x, you could return `std::make_tuple(s1, s2, s3)`, or alternatively (and much more sensibly) you could just return a `std::vector<std::string>`.